# WP7 send toast from one device to another

Tags: windows-phone-7, toast

Just wondered if it was possible to send a toast from one WP7 phone to another.

Example of use:

User A presses a button on their phone to alert other users driving nearby with status "empty" that they are needed at the GPS location of User A

If anyone can provide some insight on if this is possible, and how it can be done, it would be great.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Can you?**

No.

If I understand your question correctly, no it is not possible.

I understand your question to be "can I do this without having to implement something on a server somewhere?" And the answer to that is unfortunately "no".

What you will need to do as @softarn and @MrMDavidson alude to, you will need to implement something on the server.

**But why not?**

The reason for this is pretty simple. *IF* it was possible to do this, then it would open the door for abuse. Imagine if, without having to go through a Microsoft server, I could write a bit of code that would send push notifications constantly to all my users (who had downloaded my app of course). What happens if my users are on data plans that charge per bit? Well I've just screwed over a whole bunch of my users, and not only are they upset with me, they're upset with their stupid phone. Alternatively, what if Microsoft wants to give all windows phone users the option to get push notifications only every 15 minutes instead of immediately? Well, without operating as a go-between, Microsoft would be entirely unable to provide such functionality.

**Here's how to fake it**

So, in order to interact with toast notifications, it's a requirement that Microsoft gets to play middle man, so if needed, they can pull the plug on / monitor / regulate toast notifications on behalf of the user.

If you wanted to implement a bit of server code that *emulated* this behavior, that is certainly possible. As @MrMDavidson says, you'd basically need to take the following steps in the architecture of your app:

1. User's GPS location changes
2. WP7 app contacts a server that you own, notifying it that the user has moved
3. Your server code makes note of this, storing the data in a SQL database
4. After storing your new location, the server scans the SQL database for all other users of your app who are "nearby" and have their status set as "empty"
5. For each of the users in the database that match the criteria of being (a) nearby, and (b) having an empty status, the server code calls the user's "channel uri", sending the desired message

**To your users, it's all the same**

This would effectively accomplish your goal, and from the perspective of users, the experience would be seemless, and for all intents and purposes it will appear as if they got a notification directly from another user's phone.

Hope that clarifies things, I did assume you're familiar with the general workflow of sending Toast Notifications.

Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks @PaulHansen, I'm currently learning all of this for a university dissertation.
I'm still learning all of this, however now I know the rough way in which I can go around doing this, I start to design how I can implement such a feature.
I have a bit of know-how with how toast works, but now I know this is feasable, its time to kick into research mode to learn more and hopefully code this.

Comment: Glad I could help! Don't forget to mark correct answers for those who might be reading later :) Best of luck on your dissertation. Out of curiosity what degree would this be towards?

Comment: just a bog standard Computer Science BSc in the UK

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with this answer... the push notification URI you obtain when you register for push notifications on the phone isn't the URI of the phone - it's of the Microsoft servers. When a push notification hits this URI Microsoft's server will send that on to your phone. This allows them to do things like batching and scheduling. However Microsoft can't control **what** hits this URI - they can't (and likely never will) try and enforce a "Server Must Hit this URI" rule. Provided that another user's phone knows the notification URI that corresponds to your phone there is nothing...

Comment: ... to stop their phone from sending a push notification to the URI and having it delivered to your phone. Indeed, prior to Mango, many developers updated the app's tile by sending a tile update notification from the phone, to the notification URI, to be delivered back to the phone itself. So technically, yes, it can be done. The difficulty just becomes how to distribute the notification URIs from Phone A to Phone B to facilitate this communication.

Comment: Right, and distributing the notification URIs from Phone A and Phone B cannot be done without a server component, which was the crux of the question. I did not mean to imply Microsoft would control **what** hit the URI, only that if they didn't operate the way they do, they would be unable to. The more control Microsoft has over that flow, the better customer experience they can deliver. You are correct however in saying that it isn't the URI of the phone, I could have been more clear about that. It's the URI that *your* app obtains for the *specific* phone it's running on.

Answer (score 1):

Provided that User A's phone knows the push notification URI for User B's phone then, yes, you can send notifications from one phone to the other. However the question becomes; How do you distribute User B's notification URI to User A's phone? You'll either need an "offline" mechanism (email, for instance) or a server to act as a central repository. You're probably better off having a service layer over the top of the push notifications though to manage user-to-user relationships. Then User A's phone can say "Tell my friends that they're needed!". This can be an async-fire-and-forget call to your server. Your server can then implement retries and parallel execution to notify all User A's friends that they're needed at the location.

Answer (score -1):

Yes of course it is possible. Read on to how push notifications work, though I don't think it will be as easy as you think. You'll need (I think) a server that the phones communicate through.